# jQuery: use .hover and .change for a password input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using .hover to change the password input type to text and back to password once the mouse in not over (that works fine). But I also try to apply .change to the same selector and it seems that there is a conflict with .hover and that is never triggered.

My code

```
$('#auth_password').hover(function () {
        $('#auth_password').attr('type', 'text');
    }, function () {
        $('#auth_password').attr('type', 'password');
    }
);
$('#priv_password').hover(function () {
        $('#priv_password').attr('type', 'text');
    }, function () {
        $('#priv_password').attr('type', 'password');
    }
);

$('#auth_password, #priv_password').change( function(e){
    console.log('pass changed');
});
```

It works if the user clicks on the input textfield, then moves the mouse out of it and finally change the password.

How can I make it work, be triggered, when the user's mouse is over the input textfield?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to be more clear with what you want. For me this seems to work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/tv5cy8me/1/

Comment: Please don't change the type of password fields... There are reasons why they are masked. When your users want to see what they typed, browsers offer this since a while.

Comment: I mean that when the .hover event is ongoing the .change event is not triggered and if there is a way to make both of them work together. But I think I will follow Steven advise and don't change the type of password fields. Thanks guys.